# Equational logic - How does the free modell/free algebra/free theory work?

Tags: logic, systems-of-equations

To clarify from the beginning: I'm having a foreign source which I struggle to interpret. So, I don't even know which of the three free objects it is I'm asking about and will just try to faithfully translate the problem.

We've got a set $M$ of equations. Each equation is of the form $a = b$, where $a,b$ are terms as defined by predicate logic.

For $F\in M$, we define a *one-step term rewriting* as $\xrightarrow{F}\quad$ , which works like this:

If $G,G'$ are terms, then $G \xrightarrow{F}G'$ means that there's some substitution $\sigma$ (i.e. a number of variables are replaced by terms that don't contain the variable the're supposed to replace) 
, so that the left-hand-side of $\sigma(F)$ matches a term in $G$, and replacing this single term by the right-hand-side of $\sigma(F)$ gives us $G'$.

Further, we define $\xrightarrow{M}$ as the term rewriting system over the set $M$, so that  $G \xrightarrow{M}G'$ means that there's a chain 
$G \xrightarrow{F_1}G_1 \xrightarrow{F_2}... \xrightarrow{F_{n-1}} G_{n-1} \xrightarrow{F_n}G'$, and
 $\stackrel{\mathrm{M}}{\longleftrightarrow}$ as the reflexive, symmetric, transitive hull of $\xrightarrow{M}$, where the orientation of the equations in $M$ doesn't matter anymore 
(i.e. similar to $G \xrightarrow{M}G'$,  $G\stackrel{\mathrm{M}}{\longleftrightarrow} G'$ means there's a chain $G \stackrel{\mathrm{F_1}}{\longleftrightarrow}G_1  \stackrel{\mathrm{F_2}}{\longleftrightarrow} ...  \stackrel{\mathrm{F_{n-1}}}{\longleftrightarrow}G_{n-1} \stackrel{\mathrm{F_{n}}}{\longleftrightarrow}G'$ where $G_{i-1}\stackrel{\mathrm{F_{i}}}{\longleftrightarrow}G_i$ means either  $G_{i-1} \xrightarrow{F_i}G_i\,\,$ or $\,\,G_{i-1} \xleftarrow{F_i}G_i$  )

Now, we build two sets out of $M$: 
1) $X$ - the set that contains all variables that appear in $M$
2) $T$ - the set that contains all terms we can build using the variables and terms that appear in $M$

Now, finally, we can define the free modell/algebra/theory: 
As $\,\,\stackrel{\mathrm{F}}{\longleftrightarrow}$ is an equivalence relation, we create another set $T/M$ out of $T$, by sorting $T$ into equivalence classes, with $T/M$ being the free modell/algebra/theory and having the following property:

For all equations F: $l=r$ in $M$ and every fitting interpretation $\alpha = (T/M,\phi)$ (where $\phi$ assigns the function symbols to functions) holds $\alpha(F) = 1$, i.e. no matter how you interpret the variables, the equation holds.

This simply doesn't make sense to me, unless of cause $|U| = 1$, where of cause everything is equal. 
Let's say e.g. I have an equation $a = b$ in $M$, where $a,b$ are variables. Then, if there were two elements in $U$, then we'd be able to substitute both elements on either side, and therefore they'd be, seen by the equivalence relation, the same equivalence class, hence one element.

Same if I got an equation of two functions $f(...) = g(...)$ - as I can interpret them as I want, if there were two elements in $U$, I could simply set $f$ constant to the first element, and $g$ constant to the second element, and once again there'd only be one equivalence class if the statement actually holds.

Finally, same happens if you got a variable on one side and a function on the other.

So, is the free whatever simply pointless, or where is my grave missunderstanding?

---

For good measure I'll put the proof as in the book:

For all equations F: $l=r$ in $M$ and every fitting interpretation $\alpha = (T/M,\phi)$ (where $\phi$ assigns the function symbols to functions) holds $\alpha(F) = 1$, i.e. no matter how you interpret the variables, the equation holds.

*Proof* 
Let $\beta = (T/M,\phi,\xi) $ be a structure that fits to $\alpha$ (and where $\xi$ maps the variable symbols to elements of the universe). 
Let $\xi(x_i) = [t_i]$ where $t_i\in T$ (and $[t_i]$ stands for the equivalence class of the term $t_i$). 
Further let $\sigma$ be the substitution $x_i \rightarrow t_i $ for $x_i\in X$.

To proof $\beta(x) = 1$, we have to show $[\sigma(l)] = [\sigma(r)]$. This means $\sigma(l) \stackrel{\mathrm{M}}{\longleftrightarrow} \sigma(r)$, and follows from $l \stackrel{\mathrm{M}}{\longleftrightarrow} r$ (by a previous theorem)

---

Let's say I've got two equations:
$$
f_1(x) = f_2(y) \\
f_3(x) = f_4(x)
$$

As there's no possibility to get from $f_1 $ to $ f_3$, there's at least two equivalence classes, i.e. $[f_1(x)]$ and $[f_3(x)]$. Let's call them $0$ and $1$.

Now, as $0,1 \in T/M$, the statement says, that no matter how I interpret the functions, the equations above both will be true.

But if I now pick
$\phi(f_1) = 0 \quad$ (for all possible values of x) 
$\phi(f_2) = 1 \quad$ (for all possible values of x)

The equations $ f_1(x) = f_2(y)$ obviously is false, as all substitutions lead to $ 0 = 1$.

Comment: You have it backwards: in the free algebra, **no** two things are equal unless they **have** to be. It's not enough to say that there *exists* some way of making them equal, it has to be the case that *every* way of interpreting things makes them equal. It might help to first understand a concrete example - say, [the free group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_group). (Also, I think you've defined $T$ incorrectly: the free model should consist of equivalence classes of *terms*, not *formulas*.)

Comment: Thank you, it was terms indeed, I corrected it.

Comment: Are you really applying rewriting rules to *equations* rather than *terms*? This entire formalism seems unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: You're right again, the substitution was on equations, the rewriting rules on terms. I'll also correct this and apologize, I just don't see these mistakes as easily in English

Comment: These are largely side comments, though; do you understand my point about no two terms being equivalent unless they have to be? That's the real meat of the issue.

Comment: The point there, I think, is that there is no possible substitution of variables in any term so that technically every equation should be its own equivalence class; Or, if two terms fall together in just one case, all their cases can be rewritten so they are equal, and they therefore together share the same equivalence class

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. If one of our equations is "$x*y=y*x$," then clearly the terms "$x*y$" and "$y*x$" are equivalent, even though they're different terms ...

Comment: I think you may have missed a clause in your text. You only look at interpretations which *respect the equations* - the $\phi$ you give at the end of the answer doesn't count, precisely because it doesn't respect $f_1(x)=f_2(y)$.

Comment: There's no such thing - neither in the requirements for the statement, nor in the definitions... I guess I'll adapt to the view that there's a mistake. Thank you for your explanations and help :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have things backwards: the point is that in forming the free model, we only make two terms equivalent if the **absolutely have** to be. Just because there is *some* way of interpreting the variables/functions involved such that the terms are equal doesn't mean that they're equivalent, since what we need is that *every* way of interpreting the variables/functions involved makes the terms in question equal.

---

I think it's best to define the free model in a slightly different way. I'm going to give that definition here, and look at the specific example of a free **group**.

We start with a *language* $L$ and a set $\mathcal{E}$ of *equations* in $L$ using some set of variables $Y$. The idea is that from a set of variables $X$ disjoint from $Y$ (for simplicity), $\mathcal{E}$ determines a rewriting system - and hence an equivalence relation - on the set $T_{L, X}$ of terms in the language $L$ using the variables from $X$.

For example, take $L=\{*, ^{-1}, e\}$ to be the language of groups, $Y=\{a, b, c\}$, and $\mathcal{E}$ the set consisting of the following equations:

- $a*(b*c)=(a*b)*c$
- $a*e=a$
- $e*a=a$
- $a*a^{-1}=e$
- $a^{-1}*a=e$
- $(a^{-1})^{-1}=a$

*(I'm not claiming that $\mathcal{E}$ isn't redundant, but who cares?)*

The rewriting system corresponding to $\mathcal{E}$ is given in the obvious way: we allow substitution of terms for variables in $Y$. And we get the natural equivalence relation $\equiv_\mathcal{E}$ corresponding to this. So for example if our set of variables $X$ contains $x_1, x_2, x_3$ and $\mathcal{E}$ is as above, we have that the terms $x_1*((x_2*x_2)*x_3)$ and $(x_1*(x_2*x_2))*x_3$ are $\mathcal{E}$-equivalent. *Namely, apply the first equation in $\mathcal{E}$, substituting $x_1$ for $a$, $x_2*x_2$ for $b$, and $x_3$ for $c$.* I'm not going to precisely define this, but it should be clear what it means, and giving a precise definition is a good exercise.

Let's now look at a few cases, where $L, Y,\mathcal{E}$ are as above:

- Suppose $X=\emptyset$. Then the only terms we have are built out of $L$ itself; for example, $e^{-1}*(e*e)$ is such a term. It's not hard to show by induction that they are all $\mathcal{E}$-equivalent, by induction on the complexity of the term. So our free model in this case has a single element, and is the trivial group.
- Suppose $X=\{x\}$. We have all the same terms as in the previous case, plus new ones such as $x*(e^{-1}*x)$. We can now prove a **normal form theorem**, that every term in this context is $\mathcal{E}$-equivalent to either $e$, or a term of the form $(...((x*x)*x)*x)*x)...)$, or a term of the form $(...((x^{-1}*x^{-1})*x^{-1})*x^{-1})*x^{-1})...)$; however, we can *also* prove that this is *all* we can say. E.g. the terms $x$ and $x*x$ are **not** equivalent! I'm going to leave this argument for the end of the answer, but it should be clear intuitively that there's no way to get from $x$ to $x*x$ by repeatedly applying equations in $\mathcal{E}$.
- Suppose $X=\{x_1, x_2\}$. Now we have a more complicated situation. In the previous case, we could prove by induction on the complexity of the terms involved that $t_1*t_2$ and $t_2*t_1$ are always equivalent, whenever $t_1,t_2$ are terms in $L$ using variables from $\{x\}$. Now, however, commutativity fails: there is no way to go from $x_1*x_2$ to $x_2*x_1$ using the equations we have.
- In general, taking $X$ to be a set containing $n$ variables, we get **the free group on $n$ generators**.

---

Now, let me end by saying a bit about how we analyze these objects. In particular, I made the claim above in my second example that $x$ and $x*x$ are not equivalent; how is this proved?

There are many ways to think about it; let me give a "syntactic" one, since I think this will at first be more comfortable. To any term $t$ in $L$ with variables from $X$ we can associate a number $\#(t)$, which is the "net number of $x$s in $t$." Basically, we put $t$ into normal form, and count the number of $x$s (treating "$x^{-1}$" as "negative one $x$s"). For example, you can show:

- $\#(e*x)=1$
- $\#((x*x)^{-1}*x)=-1$

Now the key point is this: **if $t_1$ and $t_2$ are equivalent, then $\#(t_1)=\#(t_2)$.** This is pretty easy to prove by induction on the complexity of the terms, and it immediately shows that $x$ and $x*x$ aren't equivalent. So our free model **doesn't collapse**!

Now go back to the bolded statement above. It's not hard to show that the converse holds as well -  that is, if $\#(t_1)=\#(t_2)$ then $t_1$ and $t_2$ are equivalent. So we have a bijection from elements of the free model to integers! In fact, it's not hard to prove that this preserves the group structure:

> The free group on one generator is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z};+,-, 0)$.

*(Here "$-$" is a **unary** function: "$-(x)$" is just "$-x$.")*

In general, you can find an appropriate normal form theorem, and use it to give concrete descriptions of the free models which you can analyze directly. For example, a similar argument can show that in the third example, the terms "$x_1*x_2$" and "$x_2*x_1$" aren't equivalent. It's harder however, since the normal form in that situation is messier.

The most important fact, though, is the following theorem:

> Suppose $A$ satisfies (the universal closures of) the equations in $\mathcal{E}$, and $A$ is generated by a set of size $\le n$. Then there is a surjective homomorphism to $A$ from the free model of $\mathcal{E}$ on $n$ many variables (called "generators").

*(We can replace "$n$" here by any cardinal, by the way.)* This lets us immediately prove that the free group on $2$ generators isn't abelian, for example, since the quaternion group is nonabelian and generated by two elements but there is never a surjective homomorphism from an abelian group to a nonabelian group.

Comment: So, what I named $M$ and you $\sigma$. In the free group as you describe it, they seem to be written in stone and to be taken as true, while in the free model from the book, they don't assume this (or else, what'd be the point in proving that $l=r$ is true for all substitutions). <br>

Comment: @Sudix I don't understand what you're saying. First of all, I don't think I ever used a "$\sigma$" in my answer. Also, what is the "this" which they don't assume? And, what book are you using?

Comment: Regardless, I think the key point boils down to: do you understand why, in my answer, the terms "$x$" and "$x*x$" are not $\mathcal{E}$-equivalent?

Comment: Where I wrote $\sigma$ I meant $\mathcal{E}$. $x$ and $x\cdot x$ are not $\mathcal{E}$-equivalent because no matter how you choose from your rewritings and no matter where you start, you can never syntactically, i.e. by the term rewritings given by $\mathcal{E}$, conclude $x * x$ from $x$. I'd more argue with a recursive algorithm, that goes from left to right through the word, eliminates all $e$'s, and "counts" the sum of exponents of the $x$'s